# Flush subscription

Tags: ros, messages, topic, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Ros::Subscriber that receives messages from a topic. Since I'm doing some computations on the data I receive (and it requires some time), the delay with which I read new messages tend to increase.

Is there a way to "flush" all the unread messages in a topic so that I can read directly the newest one? (I'm using electric on ubuntu 11.10)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37148/flush-subscription/) by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2012-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you set the buffer size to 1 in the call to subscribe, you drop all but the newest message.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set subscriber queue_size to one

```
rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scanCb,queue_size = 1)
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-14**:
I admire your enthousiasm, but it would seem your answer is a duplicate of the answer by @Lorenz. Did you feel something was not clear enough in his answer?